# SAP HANA | JOIN with LIKE OPERATOR

Tags: sql, join, inner-join, sql-like, hana

I have two tables -

**TABLE T1** having below data -

```
COL1        COL2
1           A,B,C
```

**TABLE T2** having below data -

```
COL3        COL4
A          10
B          20
C          30
D          40
```

The output I want is -

```
COL1    COL3        COL4
1       A           10
1       B           20
1       C           30
```

T1 and T2 have around one **million** rows.

I have already tried the following:

```
select T1.COL1,T2.COL3,T2.COL4
from  T1
inner join T2 on T1.COL2 LIKE '%' || T2.COL3 || '%';

select T1.COL1,T2.COL3,T2.COL4
from  T1
inner join  T2 on instr(T1.COL2, T2.COL3 )>0;

select T1.COL1,T2.COL3,T2.COL4
from  T1
inner join  T2 on T1.COL2 LIKE_REGEXPR  T2.COL3;
```

All the three statements work fine with TEST data. But when running on actual data results in memory allocation error.

Is there a way to do this in better way?

Comment: Fix your data structure to use a junction table rather than storing lists in a string column.

Comment: I need this to populate junction table only

Comment: If you are running into an out of memory error when running these queries it suggests that your HANA instance simply does not have enough memory to perform the necessary data materialisation. As you mentioned that this is part of a data transformation to fill tables, you might want to do this in smaller batches of records.

Comment: If it's too much to handle in 1 query, then split it up? `... on  ',' || T1.COL2 || ',' LIKE '%,' || T2.COL3 || ',%'; where t1.col between ... and ...`